# C comparing times that can overflow

Tags: time, arduino, overflow

I need to detect the overflowing of an `unsigned long`.

This variable holds the amount of milliseconds since the device is running (it's an Arduino). Doing `sizeof(unsigned long)`, I have come to see it's indeed a 32-bit number. Now, since it increments every millisecond, which means the device will run for about 49 days before this value overflows.

Since it's for a home system, it isn't really advisable. Now what I'm using the number for, is comparing if the current time is larger than the previous time plus an amount of debouncing.

```
if(timeChanged + amountOfMs < currentTime){ ... }
```

Needless to say, once overflow occurs this isn't going to work anymore. What's an efficient way to solve this? I've thought about also having a second-timer as well to check if the milliseconds one has overflowed, but in the end I'll have the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This rollover issue seems to cause quite a bit of confusion...

The right answer is that you need not worry about the `millis()` rollover, as long as you do your calculation properly.

This is bad:

```cpp
if (timeChanged + amountOfMs < currentTime) { ... }
```

This is good (rollover-safe):

```cpp
if (currentTime - timeChanged > amountOfMs) { ... }
```

The reason it works is that arithmetics with unsigned integers (unsigned long in your case) reliably works modulo max+1 (`ULONG_MAX+1` is 2<sup>32</sup>). Thus, `currentTime`, `timeChanged` and their difference always have the correct value, modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. As long as you test your button more often than once every 49 days (which is likely) the difference will be in the range of an `unsigned long`, and your test will be correct.

Let put it another way: if `millis()` rolls over between `timeChanged` and `currentTime`, then the difference `currentTime - timeChanged` will be negative. But since the difference is actually computed with unsigned numbers, it will underflow and roll-over to the correct result. I do not like this explanation though, as it sounds like an error compensating another error. The truth is: if you think of unsigned numbers in terms of modular arithmetics, there is no error anywhere.

Comment: Let's make a practical example: you ask `millis()` and get (0xFFFFFFFE) stored in `timeChanged`, then you ask `millis()` again and get (0xFFFFFFFF). If amountOfMs is 10 (for example), the former test gives: `if (8 < 0xFFFFFFFF)` and it'll wrongly execute. The latter test gives: `if (1 > 10)` and it's ok.

Comment: Then, let's say you ask `millis()` for the second time and get `0x1`. The former tests gives: `if (8 < 1)` so it's correct and the second test gives: `if (3 < 10)` so it's also correct. It's easier to understand with actual numbers

Answer (score 0):

This is such a common mistake (and one that I've made myself) that the Arduino Playground has a nice, thorough, and correct answer. See https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TimingRollover

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide another example:

If your current time `millis()` is `0xfffffffb`, and you record the time of some event (say, a button press or something), using this result:

```
uint32_t button_pressed = millis();
```

`button_pressed` is now `0xfffffffb`. 10 milliseconds later, `millis()` is now `0x5`.

If you now compare those times by doing `millis() - button_pressed` i.e. `0x5 - 0xfffffffb`, the result will underflow to 10, exactly the value we want to know.

---

One way to think about this is if you do the subtraction in parts:

- If we subtract just enough to underflow the value from `millis()` (which is currently `0x5` in our example), `0x5` - `0x6` underflows to `0xffffffff`
- Leaving us `0xfffffff5` from our `button_pressed` variable to subtract (`0xfffffffb` - `6`).
- Finally, `0xffffffff` - `0xfffffff5` = `10`

---

```
uint32_t time_elapsed = 0x5 - 0xfffffffb;

printf("%lu\n", time_elapsed); // prints 10
```

In godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/55he4v183

Answer (score -3):

You can create a new if loop checking the condition : if(currentTime == 0xFFFFFFFE)

If this is the condition, next millisecond will overflow your variable. So at this point you can manually reset it to zero and goto loop where it starts from zero.

This might or might not help your situation. I can't say for sure because you haven't shared any further details about your code.

Comment: I guess an option would indeed be to check once the number is high enough to reset all values and the timer to the maximum debouncing time. Thanks!

Comment: This would be unreliable as you are depending on the code running exactly at that time, which it may not. Notthe right answer at all, see my answer for a reliable way to detect rollover.

Comment: ok sorry that a mistake as i was typing in hurry. instead of using if(currentTime == 0xFFFFFFFE); you should use if(currentTime >= 0xFFFFFFFE). now i don't see any difference between @phil's and my answer.

Comment: Still a fail. Once the current time has rolled over it will be significantly less than the value you have suggested, won't it? Big, big difference between our answers. Like I've used mine for real and it works, whereas you clearly haven't used yours, because if you had you'd know that it doesn't work.

Answer (score -3):

Define two variables, I'm going to call them 'now' and 'lastNow'.

```
unsigned long now;
unsigned long lastNow = 0;
```

In your loop you can now do this:

```
now = millis();
if (now < lastNow) {
    // rollover!
}
lastNow = now;
```

Nice and reliable regardless of how frequently (or infrequently) you loop.